# Cloudformation - Give a property to an S3 Bucket Resource if it meets a condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, conditional-statements, aws-cloudformation

I basically want to check if the environment is env or dev, and if it is then enable versioning. If not, do nothing. I used the example for the AWS documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html

I am getting an error though in my stack

> Value of property VersioningConfiguration must be an object

My Condition Cloudformation

```
Conditions:
    EnvCheck: !Or [!Equals [!Ref environment, test], !Equals [!Ref environment, dev]]
```

Bucket Cloudformation

```
Resources:
  SecurityS3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
        ...
        VersioningConfiguration:
            !If
                - EnvCheck
                - 
                  Status: Enabled
                - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
```

Answer (score -1):

It's actually pretty straightforward. As soon as you specify the `VersioningConfiguration` property for the bucket, you have to specify the value for it, which has to be an object with a property `Status` according to [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-versioningconfig.html).

So either you'll have to pass in the other value for `Status` (i.e., `Suspended`) or you'll have to place your `!If` statement differently so the `VersioningConfiguration` property key is not set when you don't want versioning enabled on the bucket.